# Python bs4 Unknown Error: " return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 'id' "

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am experimenting with python web scraping. I am following a tutorial @ https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/ and have encountered an error message which I don't really understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1321, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'id'
```

The error code came up after I ran the following code in my terminal 
[image]

where mathematicians.py is the following:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def simple_get(url):
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None
    except RequestExeception as e:
        log_error("Error during requests to {0} : {1}".format(url, str(e))) #prints the error msg lol
        return None

def is_good_response(resp):
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower() #converts all headers to lowercase
    return (resp.status_code == 200 and content_type is not None and content_type.find('html') >-1)
    #return the status_code and that content is not empty as well as finding the word html??

def log_error(e):
    print(e)
```

Can someone help explain what is the error about? (I read online it is something to do with the absence of id tag? But I am still confused...)

Comment: Inside your for loop, `if li['id']`, error says `li` doesn't have `id` and you're trying to access it. put a print statement above `if` and `print(li)`. You will see

Comment: Its better to paste your code as text instead of posting an image. Better yet, instead of just the console session, a small .py file including an html example that shows the problem. Then we can post suggested changes.

Comment: All this means is that the selected `<li>` element doesn't have an `id` attribute. Its just telling you something about the html.

Comment: thks! I found the problem and how to solve it alr

Comment: @Red If you found the answer you can post it as a reply to your question to help someone with the same problem!